# linq to sql, insert many to many relationship

Tags: linq-to-sql, many-to-many

I have 3 tables.

Post: PostID, PostName

Tag: TagID, TagName

PostTag: PostTagID, PostID, TagID

Following codes are how I insert many to many. but I use SubmitChanges() three times,I dont think that's the best way to do it. I can use stored procedure. but want to know if there's a better way to do it without stored procedure.

```
           Post post = new Post()
            {
                PostName =  entity.PostName
            };

            context.Posts.InsertOnSubmit(post);
            context.SubmitChanges();

            Tag tag = new Tag()
            {
                TagName = entity.Tags
            };

            context.Tags.InsertOnSubmit(tag);
            context.SubmitChanges();

            PostTag pt = new PostTag()
            {
                PostID = post.PostID,
                TagID = tag.TagID
            };

            context.PostTags.InsertOnSubmit(pt);
            context.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to SubmitChanges three times.  If you have the proper foreign keys in place, you can simply add the references to each other in code then SubmitChanges once.  LINQ is awesome like that.

```
    Post post = new Post()
    {
        PostName =  entity.PostName
    };

    context.Posts.InsertOnSubmit(post);

    Tag tag = new Tag()
    {
        TagName = entity.Tags
    };

    context.Tags.InsertOnSubmit(tag);

    PostTag pt = new PostTag()
    {
        Post = post,
        Tag = tag
    };

    context.PostTags.InsertOnSubmit(pt);
    context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: that is what I thought, I should not need it three times. I do have proper FK in place. I have 2 FKs. the problem is if I dont do SubmitChanges, I wont get new PostID and TagID back. how do i insert "PostTag" table?  can you show me some codes how to do it properly.

Comment: Correct, it is a bit counter intuitive, but LINQ will actually map the new PostID and TagID automatically on the one SubmitChanges call.  I have posted a code sample, but it's in an edit and needs to be approved before you can see it.

Comment: Thank you, Hspain. cannot wait to see your code. I removed first two "SubmitChanges", it failed immediately, because "TagID" and "PostID" didnt get generated.  the best I can do is to remove the first SubmitChanges from my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also call InsertOnSubmit only on one of these objects. Compare with [Insert into many-to-many relationship tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030192/insert-into-many-to-many-relationship-tables)