# Insert into many-to-many relationship tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, many-to-many, insertonsubmit

Simple scenario

```
[ClientTable]: ClientId, ClientName, Phone, Age
[CityTable]: CityID, CityName, Country
[ClientCityTable]: ClientCityID, ClientID, CityID

Client client = new Client("John", 123456789, 40);
City city = new City("NY", USA);
ClientCity clientCity = new ClientCity(client, city);
```

Should I make InsertOnSubmit on every object(table) or only on clientCity?
Or it doesn't matter? Where's the difference?

**EDIT**

I'ms asking if should I make

```
DatabaseDC dc = new DatabaseDC(connectionString);
dc.Client.InsertOnSubmit(client);
dc.City.InsertOnSubmit(city);
dc.ClientCity.InsertOnSubmit(clientCity);
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

or only

```
DatabaseDC dc = new DatabaseDC(connectionString);
dc.ClientCity.InsertOnSubmit(clientCity);//because this object has references to client and city
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

?

**EDIT 2**

I made a few attempts and even of I use `InsertOnSubmit` only on `client`, entries are inserted also to `City` and `ClientCity`. How should I do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you have to insure that the linked tables exist before the insert or you may get an error (depends if you have constrained your sql tables).

You can also create custom stored procedure calls for the inserts and updates, these procedures could insure the linked tables are correct.

IMHO linq-to-sql is good for making complicated selections but not so easy to use for updating the database.  (Often I've seen it create serious performance bottlenecks.)

Comment: So if I understand you correctly: I can make InsertOnSubmit on every table but it's not necessary? Then it will be way of checking tables Client and City? And method with only InsertOnSubmit on ClientCity will also work correctly?

Comment: I wonder whether the call InsertOnSubmit on each of the 3 above mentioned objects will not cause a double double entry Client and City?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking.  linq-to-sql does not "cascade".  You have to do it by "hand".  If you insert the same thing more than once you will have it multiple times.

Comment: I tried both options and in my mdf database there's no difference. Is it ok?

Comment: linq-to-sql is fine for updates as long as you do not try to do anything in Batches

Comment: @Saint - You would do the first one if the client and city don't yet exist -- you would do the second one if they already did.

Answer (score 1):

From the result, it really does not matter. Both ways are correct.

Advantages of the second (only one insertonsubmit)

- cleaner
- less code

Advantage of the first one

- for people who are new to Linq2sql easier to read/understand
- also if there are no correct references, an insert will be done (or is this a disadvantage?, up to you)

As you already found out, the result is the same.